# yfinance in Visual Studio Code

Tags: yfinance

The line

> yf.pdr_override() #Activate yahoo finance workspace

causes

```
yf.pdr_override() #Activate yahoo finance workspace
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'fix_yahoo_finance' has no attribute 'pdr_override' (most likely due to a circular import)

though it works fine in Python IDLE.

do I need to install anithing on VSC?

The line

> yf.pdr_override() #Activate yahoo finance workspace

causes

```
yf.pdr_override() #Activate yahoo finance workspace
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'fix_yahoo_finance' has no attribute 'pdr_override' (most likely due to a circular import)

though it works fine in Python IDLE.

do I need to install anithing on VSC?